# Using createBrowserRouter and createRoutesFromElements to create routes and navigate between to components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, the `Homepage` and `AboutMe` components that I would like to navigate to using their respective links `About Me` and `Home`.

Homepage.js

```
function HomePage(){
    return(
        <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
    )
}
export default HomePage;
```

AboutMe.js

```
function AboutMe(){
    return(
        <h1>About Me</h1>
    )
}

export default AboutMe;
```

With the code below, without the navigation links, I'm able to navigate to the `Homepage` component using `http://localhost:3001/` and the `AboutMe` component using `http://localhost:3001/about-me`

```
import React from "react";
import AboutMe from "./AboutMe";
import HomePage from "./Homepage";
import { 
  createBrowserRouter, 
  createRoutesFromElements, 
  Route, 
  RouterProvider,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';


// router and routes
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route >
      <Route index path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="about-me" element={<AboutMe />} />
    </Route>
  )
)

function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  )
}

export default App;
```

But when I try to add the corresponding links as below, I get an error that reads

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import AboutMe from "./AboutMe";
import HomePage from "./Homepage";
import { 
  createBrowserRouter, 
  createRoutesFromElements, 
  Route, 
  RouterProvider,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom';


// router and routes
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route >
      <Route index path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="about-me" element={<AboutMe />} />
    </Route>
  )
)

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="nam">
        <Link to="/" className="nav-item">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about-me" className="nav-item">About Me</Link>
      </nav>

        <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to wrap the Route provider around the app component.

```
function App() {
  return (
<RouterProvider router={router}>
    <div>
      <nav className="nam">
        <Link to="/" className="nav-item">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about-me" className="nav-item">About Me</Link>
      </nav> 
    </div>
</RouterProvider>
  )
}
```

Please give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Link components should indeed be in the context of RouterProvider to work.

But RouterProvider doesn't accept children (Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouterProviderProps') (at least with react-router-dom 6.18.0)

When declaring your routes, you can use root route element

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<Layout />}> // <=========
      <Route index path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
      <Route path="about-me" element={<AboutMe />} />
    </Route>
  )
)
```

in Layout.tsx

```
const Layout: FC<IProps> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="nam">
        <Link to="/" className="nav-item">Home</Link>
        <Link to="/about-me" className="nav-item">About Me</Link>
      </nav>
      <Outlet /> // <== e.g to display AboutMe content if route is "about-me"
    </>
  );
};
```